# Does an attack hit if it exactly matches the target's AC?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, armor-class, attack-roll

For an attack to successfully hit a given Armor Class, would it need to get a number *higher* than the Armor Class? Or does it hit if the total exactly equals the Armor Class value as well?

Does the answer to this question change depending on what type of attack it is?

Comment: Related: [How much does “Defender Wins Ties” affect challenge rating math?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133532/how-much-does-defender-wins-ties-affect-challenge-rating-math)

Comment: Related (but not duplicate because AC and DCs are mechanically different): [Do you have to beat or equal a DC?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68115)

Comment: "meets it, beats it" is simple to remember and sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the PHB section on [Attack Rolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#AttackRolls), emphasis added:

> If the total of the roll plus modifiers *equals or exceeds* the target's Armor Class (AC), the attack hits.

Comment: The mnemonic that I sling around is "Ties go to the roller."

Comment: Or as I just heard in [chat]: "Tie goes to the die." or "die wins tie"

Comment: Or, if you want an equivalent to "equals or exceeds": "meets or beats".

Comment: I call ACs and DCs the 'target number'. You succeed if you hit the target.

Comment: Unless you rolled a natural 1. Even if you equal or beat the AC it doesn’t matter. But I assume most people know that.

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier True, but not part of the question asked so not part of the answer provided.